# How does File.read("| echo mystring") work?

Tags: ruby

I found this in some code I was working on. It was designed to work around a requirement to read a keyfile from disk. In production the contents of the keyfile were in an environment variable.

Old code:

```
key = File.read('path/to/key.pem')
```

New code:

```
key = File.read('| echo $KEY_VARIABLE')
```

How does this work?

Comment: That is.... a weird way to read the env var. Should be `ENV['KEY_VARIABLE']`.

Comment: @sergio the library which receives the var only supports a filename as parameter

Comment: FWIW, this works with all commands: `File.read('| uptime')`. I assume it is a feature `IO` provides, but I've never seen it and it looks interesting. Scary. But interesting.

Comment: @berkes: never seen it either :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [IO docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/IO.html):

> A string starting with “|” indicates a subprocess. The remainder of the string following the “|” is invoked as a process with appropriate input/output channels connected to it.

The "channels connected" bit means that the output of the process will become the input for `read`. So in this example the result from the `echo` of the environment variable can be read.

Comment: TIL. If you weren't already whitelisting the input for user generated filenames in your gem, application or tool, this is the moment to do so. `/reports/1337?filename=%7C%20rm%20-rf%20%2F%20--no-preserve-root`